# 3D printer restarts itself

Tags: diy-3d-printer

I have a 3D printer that when I try and heat the hot bed the printer shuts down and restarts.

It is an IDEX printer, when I heat the nozzles, they heat up fine, when I move the X-axis it moves fine. Z is fine and Y is fine as well, so I eliminated the steppers having a short or nozzles. The company sent me a new hot bed, I plugged it in and it did the same same exact thing. No viable burn marks on any component on the controller board that I can see. Any ideas where to go from here? I want to say it is the power supply but I do not know how to check this. I have some basic electrical knowledge but have now gotten in deeper then my knowledge. The wires have all been checked for resistance and show good results. Any ideas or links would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! I've tidied up the question, I hope you can add by [edit] when it restarts. Furthermore, which company? Why a new bed? When does the restart happens? Is it a DIY scratch build or an existing brand? Please help us out so we can help you!

Comment: Hi Oscar and Thank you.

Comment: Hi Oscar and Thank you. It is a purchased printer. A Sovol sv-04 Idex printer. The company after e-mailing them had me try some things. one was to unhook the bed heat wire Red at the green block it is connected to turn on printer hit PLA on Temp and see what happens. it did not shut down right away after a few min. it went to error need to restart did not come up to temp or something to that effect. so they thought it was the bed and sent me a new one. i used multi meter today to measure voltage in and out of cpu wass suggested. 121 v in . 52 v out the sticker on cpu says 500 watt 24 v 21 a .

Comment: this was measured in DC mode on multi meter not a electrician just some basic knowledge. ?